# Long polynomial expansion with 34 roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, contest-math

[image]

This is a very tricky problem, I just need a few hints. I think the $(-x^{17})$ is also there for a specific trick. In the end if it is $ax^{17}$, I see that $a = 17 - 1 + 1 = 17$.

Also, another possible approach is:

$$(1 + x + \cdots + x^{17})^2 = x^{17}$$

$$1 + x + \cdots + x^{17} = x^{17/2}$$

But that doesn't do much. **Only hints please!**

### **UPDATE:**

$$P(x)=0\implies x\ne 1.$$

By the geometric series formula this changes to:

$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{17}  x^n \right)^2 = x^{17} \text{ where } |x| < 1.$$

$$ \left( \frac{1 - x^{18}}{1-x}  \right)^2 = x^{17}.$$

$$(1 - x^{18})^2 = (1-x)^2(x^{17}) = x^{19} - 2x^{18} + x^{17}.$$

$$x^{36} - 2x^{18} + 1 = x^{19} - 2x^{18} + x^{17}.$$

$$x^{36} - x^{19} - x^{17} + 1 = 0.$$

$$x^{19}(x^{17} - 1) - (x^{17} - 1) = 0.$$

$$(x^{19} - 1)(x^{17} - 1) = 0.$$

With zero prod. property, we have to use roots of unity.

$$x^{19} = 1 = e^{2\pi i*k}.$$

$$1\ne x = e^{2\pi i \cdot k/19}.$$

$$1\ne x = e^{2\pi i \cdot k/17} \space \text{for the other case}.$$

the smallest root obviously is $a_1 = 1/19, a_2 = 1/17, a_3 = 2/19, a_4 = 2/17, a_5 = 3/19$.

$$\sum a_k = \frac{6}{19} + \frac{3}{17} = \frac{102 + 57}{323} = \frac{159}{323} = \frac{m}{n}$$

$m + n = 482$.

Comment: I would like a hint: exactly where did you get this problem?

Comment: Just a thought: if you can establish that $|x|<1$, you can come up with a simple*r* equation by multiplying both sides by $(1-x)^2$.

Comment: @user170231, I'll update it with your hint

Comment: @WillJagy, this was a past AIME Problem, I think 04, Im not sure

Comment: @user170231, I edited it, but still no good progress, please take a look!

Comment: You can factor by grouping: $x^{36}-x^{19}=x^{19}\left(x^{17}-1\right)$

Comment: @user170231, one more edit coming up (it will under the same header though). Its late night here, cant blame me haha =)

Comment: Perhaps the answer is $m+n=482$.

Comment: @user170231, edited.

Comment: @GEdgar, I got the same answer, but I do not have an answer key for confirmation.

Comment: Found it -- #13 in Set I, 2004 [ http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2004_AIME_I_Problems ] ; good memory, WillJagy!

Comment: I changed  first line in  the answer  above, following "UPDATE" : You just need $x\ne 1$. Added that in what followed.Nice solution.They key was to see the factoring  $(x^{19}-1)(x^{17}-1)$. And I added some punctuation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the update to the question:

---

The value of $|z_k| < 1$, because $(1 + x + ... + x^{17})^2 > x^{17}$.

By the geometric series formula this changes to:

$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{17}  x^n \right)^2 = x^{17} \space \text{where} \space |x| < 1$$

$$ \left( \frac{1 - x^{18}}{1-x}  \right)^2 = x^{17}$$

$$(1 - x^{18})^2 = (1-x)^2(x^{17}) = x^{19} - 2x^{18} + x^{17}$$

$$x^{36} - 2x^{18} + 1 = x^{19} - 2x^{18} + x^{17}$$

$$x^{36} - x^{19} - x^{17} + 1 = 0$$

$$x^{19}(x^{17} - 1) - (x^{17} - 1) = 0$$

$$(x^{19} - 1)(x^{17} - 1) = 0$$

With zero prod. property, we have to use roots of unity.

$$x^{19} = 1 = e^{2\pi i*k}$$

$$x = e^{2\pi i *k/19}$$

$$x = e^{2\pi i *k/17} \space \text{for the other case}$$

the smallest root obviously is $a_1 = 1/19, a_2 = 1/17, a_3 = 2/19, a_4 = 2/17, a_5 = 3/19$.

$$\sum a_k = \frac{6}{19} + \frac{3}{17} = \frac{102 + 57}{323} = \frac{159}{323} = \frac{m}{n}$$

$m + n = 482$.

Comment: Is this your answer? It's now been incorporated verbatim into the Q.

Comment: It's the other way around. I copied the answer from the question (and made it community wiki so I wouldn't get any rep I don't deserve for it) to get this question off the "unanswered" list.